# Convert RDL to RDLC in vs 2013

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, visual-studio-2013, rdlc, rdl

Hi I am trying to covert rdl file to rdlc.

rdl created in vs2013(SQL Server 2014) and I am add this also in vs 2013 project.
I rename rdl file to rdlc and place in project.assign data set ,but when run no error occurred but also report will not shown.

but if I add report in project using **add new item** its working fine .

any idea/possibility why its not working and how I make it working?

I also try https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252109%28v=vs.80%29.aspx[^] but not working.